# How to ignore blank values in a combobox to be used in a worksheet function?

Tags: excel, variables, worksheet-function, vba

I would like to use the `CountIf` function, but if either of my variables (a or B) are blank (userform combobox not selected with a value) the function does not calculate.  Listed below is the `CountIfs` function.  I would like to ignore the "D" variable if it is blank and still `Countif`.

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim C As String
Dim LastTarget As range
Dim LastTarget2 As range

Set LastTarget = ActiveCell
Set LastTarget2 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Userform 4.3.xlsm")


a = ComboBoxA.value
B = ComboBox1.value

'Counts & Coverages based on plan code selection
LastTarget = Application.CountIfs(wb1.Sheets("Carrier").range("BG:BG"), a, wb1.Sheets("Carrier").range("AH:AH"), B)
```

Unload me

End Sub

Comment: please add the rest of your code, what is `D` ? how does it get it's value ?

Comment: Updated variables from C&D to a & B.  If combobox1 is not selected I would like the function to still calculate or use the countif function but not error when blank.